Weight symmetry error

I activated weight symmetry to have both sides with the same weight.
But when i move on part in pose mode ( x symmetry off ) doesn’t work, looks like grab the other side too.

Weight symmetry does exactly that, it symmetrizes the weight. That does not mean it automatically changes the weight to a different bone group...

Got it and thanks for the answer, so, what should i do to mirror the same weight painted in the Left side to the right side without affecting the side of the arm that i am working with in pose mode. I mean the weight mirroring looks ok but if i move the left arm, that drags the mirrored weight paint from the right arm too.
